# Getting NPE when trying to do spark streaming with Twitter

Tags: spark-streaming

I am new to SparkStreaming, when tried to submit the Spark-Twitter streaming job, getting the following error:

```
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0,sandbox.hortonworks.com):java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.decodeFileNameInURI(Utils.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:404)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:396)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:396)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:192)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)

System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf,  Seconds(2))
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,None, filters)
val hashTags = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))
val topCounts60 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60))
                 .map{case (topic, count) => (count, topic)}
                 .transform(_.sortByKey(false))
topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val topList = rdd.take(10)
  println("\nPopular topics in last 60 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
  topList.foreach{case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count))}
})
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Any clue why I am getting this NPE?? Any help on how to debug this further?

Comment: this `val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,None, filters)` looks broken to me, should be some `twitterAuth` object there

Comment: Replaced the "None" with this method call and its still failing at same error:  def creds(): Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization]= { object auth{
val config = new twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder().setOAuthConsumerKey("****").setOAuthConsumerSecret("****").setOAuthAccessToken("****").setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("****").build}
        val twitter_auth = new TwitterFactory(auth.config)
        val a = new twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization(auth.config)
        val atwitter : Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization] = 
        Some(twitter_auth.getInstance(a).getAuthorization())
         atwitter}

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a bit, in my spark-submit script, Job jar file got added to the --jar list and getting this error. But this seems to be a bug in the spark-core package.